# Program doesnt work on other laptops which is 32bit

Tags: node.js

Help, my program is using 64bit desktop, and when i try to run it to 32bit laptop it displays error

in command prompt:

> > npm run dev

it displays an error of : %1 is not  is not a valid win32 application

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my problem, there is a specific node_sqlite3.node (located at node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding) file for 32bit and 64 bit